# Is it possible to intercept a save or load event in spring-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In `spring-data-jpa`, we can use JPA's annotations like `@PrePersist` and friends to intercept save/load events.

In `spring-data-mongodb`, for the same purpose we can use [lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

Is there anything similar in `spring-data-elasticsearch`?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are no lifecycle hooks in spring-data-elasticsearch like they exist in spring-data-mongodb. It sure would be nice to have them.

I opened [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-587) for this.

**Edit:**

As Roman wrote in his answer, this has been implemented in  version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know elasticsearch but as it is Spring Data I would suggest you use an EventHandler like this:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(YourDomainClass.class)
public class YourDomainClassEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleYourDomainClassCreate(YourDomainClass yourDomainClass) {
        //do some action
    }
}
```

There are also annotations like `@HandleBeforeSave`, `@HandleAfterSave` and a few more. It's part of spring-data-rest-core library.

Comment: Thank you @Mirko, but `@HandleBeforeSave` and friends are not core Spring Data annotations, they are specific to spring-data-rest, so they are not available in spring-data-elasticsearch. So we have one more example of how it can be done in other spring-data-* modules :)

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Ok sorry I couldn't help. Hope someone else might know an answer to this. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`EntityCallback` support was implemented a few months ago, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks

Currently, after-save, after-convert, before-convert entity callbacks are supported, both reactive and blocking.